# How do you require local Javascript files with Rails 6 / webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker

So this seems like a simple question but I can't manage to find any links about it.

I am using coffee-rails and have a file `app/javascript/packs/post_form.js.coffee`. I am including it in my HTML page via `javascript_pack_tag 'post_form'`.

The question is, how do I load a dependent JS file from here? I tried putting inside `post_form.js.coffee`:

```
HelperFunctions = require("lib/helper_functions")
```

And then in `app/javascript/lib/helper_functions.js.coffee`:

```
module.exports = {
  UsefulMethod: -> console.log("I'm helpful!")
}
```

I'm getting

**> Cannot find module 'lib/helper_functions'**

My `config/webpack/environments.js` file is as follows:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee =  require('./loaders/coffee')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))


environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to require it relatively. Try this:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/post_form.coffee
HelperFunctions = require("../lib/helper_functions");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. I tried putting a file `test.js` in the same directory as the script where I'm `require`ing it from. I couldn't get that to work with any permutation. With or without file extension, with or without `./`. Nothing works.

Comment: Strange, it's working for me. Don't use `file.js.coffee`, use `file.coffee` for coffee and `file.js` for JS file. Did you run `rails webpacker:install:coffee` to install coffeescript? You don't need to mention extensions in `require` whether that is `.js` or `.coffee`.

Comment: Can you confirm that changing all your `.js.coffee` file to `.coffee` and restarting server still gives the same error?

Comment: The reason for my confusion, was that I saw in a tutorial that the `pack` files can have extension `.js.coffee` and that is what I have - it works in that case. But it seems that when using `require` we reference plan `.coffee` extension.